# Concurrency in Matrix Multiplication/Addition

Tags: java, matrix, concurrency

I have to create a program that simulates concurrent matrix addition and multiplication. I realize that if I have 3 matrices: A, B, and C, and I want to calculate A+B = C or A*B = C, then the maximum amount of threads I can create are (rows in C) * (columns in C), since each final position in matrix C can be calculated independent of the other positions.

My real question is this: if I have a interface `MatrixMath` which has methods `multiply(), add(), print()`, how can I ensure that when the `add()` or `multiply()` methods terminate, all the changes are done being written to the product or sum matrix?

Example:

```java
class MatrixMathImplementation implements MatrixMath {

  public void multiply(int[][]A, int[][]B, int[][]C) {
    //multiply the two matrices, spawning m*n threads
    //haven't coded this yet
  }

  public void add(int[][]A, int[][]B, int[][]C) {
      //add the two matricies, spawning m*n threads
      //First: Check that A, B, and C are all the same size
      if (A.length == B.length && A.length == C.length &&
        A[0].length == B[0].length && A[0].length == C[0].length) {

        for (int row=0; row < A.length; row++) {
          for (int col=0; col < A[0].length; col++) {
              new MatrixSumThread(A,B,C,row,col);
          }
        }    
      } else {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Arrays are not the same size.");
      }
    }
  }

  public void print() {
    //print the given matrix
    //doesn't need to be concurrent, haven't coded this yet either.
  }
}
```

In the code, `MatrixSumThread` creates a runnable that will calculate the sum needed for the specific row and column, and put it into that row and column in matrix C. I'll make a similar runnable class for `MatrixProductThread`.

Any ideas on how to make sure that if I have:

```
someMatrixMathObject.add(A,B,C);
someMatrixMathObject.multiply(A,B,C);
```

That I can ensure the `add` finishes before the `multiply`, or vice versa? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Push the tasks into a `Collection<Callable<Void>>` and then chuck all those into `ExecutorService.invokeAll` - this will return when its done. P.S. do you really think it's worth using threads to add each pair of numbers? (hint; no, it's not).

Comment: I would listen to @BoristheSpider, but if you want to handle everything yourself, then you should read [this](http://javahowto.blogspot.no/2007/05/when-to-join-threads.html) article about joining threads. "Let's say I need to spawn multiple threads to do the work, and continue to the next step only after all of them complete. ... The key point is to use Thread.join() method."

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks for the tip, I'll look into that! And realistically: no, I do not think it's worth using multiple threads. This is for a University assignment however in which the point is to maximize controlling different threads in this situation, not necessarily creating a realistic scenario.

Comment: @atomman thanks for the tip! Article seems helpful.

Comment: Doing a thread for each pair of values seems senseless, I can see how dividing the matrix in submatrixes for multiple threads to operate on would be sensible though.

Comment: [this example](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html#ai) would help you buddy.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, here's how you work with raw threads:

```
Thread t = new Thread(); // or subclass thereof
t.start();  // make sure to not start threads in the constructor; start explicitly
t.join();   // waits for the thread to finish
```

in your case:

```
// create a list to hold all your threads, above the for loops
List<MatrixSumThread> threads = new ArrayList<MatrixSumThread>();
// for() { ...
// make sure MatrixSumThread doesn't call start() in its constructor
MatrixSumThread t = new MatrixSumThread(A,B,C,row,col);
threads.add(t);
t.start();
```

then later, after you're done with for-loops, join all the threads:

```
for (MatrixSumThread t in threads) {
  t.join();
}
```

Comment: Please include more details and explain how the OP can use the above code to fix the situation at hand.

Comment: @iluxa Thanks; implemented something similar to this and it worked